# Move row in sheet to another sheet via api

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am unable to find a way to move rows between sheets in Smartsheet via API.  There is a move row command in Smartsheet which moves the row data and preserves all attachments and discussions.  Is this available through API?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Move Row(s)" capability is not available in the current version of the Smartsheet API (1.1).  However, the next version of the Smartsheet API (2.0) -- which is scheduled for release later this month -- will include the ability to move row(s) from one sheet to another.

If you haven't already subscribed to the Smartsheet Developer Newsletter, you can do so here: https://www.smartsheet.com/developers (via the "Get Developer Updates" form in the bottom-right area of the page). We'll be notifying subscribers via email when API 2.0 is available.

Comment: You can mimic this behavior in 1.1 by retrieving the row from the sheet ([get sheet](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.4930jur8qsvs)), inserting it into a new sheet ([update sheet](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.l666x43ggee5)) and then deleting the row ([delete row](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.azdqot5sfq8)) from the original sheet. It will definitely be easier when 2.0 is available.

Comment: Update:  Smartsheet API 2.0 is now publicly available!  See here for info about the Move Row(s) operation:  http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#move-row(s)-to-another-sheet